# FQL Javascript: How can I pass in a graph result into an FQL query

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-javascript-sdk

Say I have mutual friends via

```
mutual_friends=FB.api('/me/mutualfriends/'+target)
```

How do I then use that response in an FQL query. I.e say I wanted to get the first names of all of those users.  I took a shot in the dark with this, but it didn't work (and I didn't expect it to).

```
mutual_friends=FB.api('/me/mutualfriends/'+target);
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
            showLoader(false);

            //http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/
            var query       =  FB.Data.query('select name from user where uid in' + mutual_friends);

            console.dir(query);

    });
```

Do I just have to format the query by iterating? I.e `uid in (response.data[0].name, response.data[1].name ...)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I just have to format the query by iterating? I.e uid in
>   (response.data[0].name, response.data[1].name ...)?

yes, that is what you can do, And also be sure to use `response.data[0].id` instead of `response.data[0].name`.

Or another, more direct avenue might be something like this:

```
SELECT uid, first_name, last_name, pic_small
FROM user
WHERE uid IN (
    SELECT uid2
    FROM friend
    WHERE uid1 = ['sourceID']
)
AND uid IN (
    SELECT uid2
    FROM friend
    WHERE uid1 = ['targetID']
)
```